An invalid token was provided. Discord.js
Tried change the token parameters and still got this issue, i've only started the bot and here is what i got, never saw this happened before.
r.js:136
const invalidToken = new DiscordjsError(ErrorCodes.TokenInvalid);
^
Error [TokenInvalid]: An invalid token was provided.
at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\Trevor\Desktop\NeuroDiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:136:26)
at Client.login (C:\Users\Trevor\Desktop\NeuroDiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:228:21)
at Object. (C:\Users\Trevor\Desktop\NeuroDiscord\index.js:18:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'TokenInvalid'
}
The code that i'm using:
require('dotenv/config')
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js")
const { OpenAI } = require("openai")
require("dotenv/config")

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
})

client.once(Events.ClientReady, (ClientUser) =>{
    console.log(`logged in as ${clientUser.user.tag}`)
})

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

Node.js v20.12.2
tried to repeat all the stuff was in tutorial and thought that is gonna run, but still got an Error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I got the same issue, I even directly pasted the token in it without the dotenv just to try if it even changes anything - nope. Even after I generated a new token on the dev page - still no, "An invalid token was provided.".
